# Как включить отображение скрытых файлов в вим?

Tags: текст, vim

Nerdtree стоит, но в дереве не отображает файлы начинающиеся на точку (.env, ,htaccess), помогите пожалуйста

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5057359/4827341

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Сочетанием символов `gh` можно включать/выключать. Посмотрите `:help netrw-hide`:

> ```
> As a quick shortcut, one may press
>          gh
> to toggle between hiding files which begin with a period (dot) and not hiding
> them.
> ```

Comment: В вопросе речь идёт о [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree), не о netrw.